# google phpmailer error SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm trying to use google php mailer but i get a lot of error messages. I've uploaded a fresh copy to test again and i get this error :

```
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host
```

and after debugging I got this message

```
SMTP -> ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Network is unreachable (101) 
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host
```

I've enabled IMAP and POP forwarding from gmail and opened this page
    https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha
clicked continue and refreshed the page to send from and it's not working i get Mail error: SMTP Connect() failed.

Here's the code:

```
<?php
require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
define('GUSER', 'username@gmail.com'); // GMail username
define('GPWD', 'password'); // GMail password
function smtpmailer($to, $from, $from_name, $subject, $body) { 
global $error;
$mail = new PHPMailer();  // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;  // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;  // authentication enabled
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 465; 
$mail->Username = GUSER;  
$mail->Password = GPWD;           
$mail->SetFrom($from, $from_name);
$mail->Subject = $subject;
$mail->Body = $body;
$mail->AddAddress($to);
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    $error = 'Mail error: '.$mail->ErrorInfo; 
    return false;
} else {
    $error = 'Message sent!';
    return true;
}
}

$msg = 'Hello World';
$subj = 'test mail message';
$to = 'username@yahoo.com';
$from = 'username@gmail.com';
$name = 'any name';

if (smtpmailer($to, $from, $name, $subj, $msg)) {
echo 'Yippie, message send via Gmail';
} else {
if (!smtpmailer($to, $from, $name, $subj, $msg, false)) {
    if (!empty($error)) echo $error;
} else {
    echo 'Yep, the message is send (after doing some hard work)';
}
}
?>
```

How to solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried port 25?

Comment: Try $mail->Host = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

Comment: changing port to 25 didn't work and ssl://smtp.gmail.com didn't work too

Comment: after uploading another copy of the files I get this error : SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host

Answer (score 1):

check the file php.ini on server. verify if the line openssl.dll is uncommented